# Print receipt from cash register in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

**Problem**

Output a receipt of purchased items. Inputs:

- products_text_path: Products are found in a text file in `<barcode>:<name>:<price>` line format.
- purchased_items_set: The purchased items are given as a list of integer barcodes. Same item be found several times.
- discount_rules_text_path: There are discount rules in a text file in `<barcode>:<min_quantity>:<discount>` format which mean that buying more than `min_quantity` of the `barcode` item will give you a `discount` (given as the discount percentage /1)

**Goal**

Readable code that handles very large amount of input

**Example**

```
Products:
- 123:banana:0.5
- 789:apple:0.4

Discounts:
- 123:2:0.2 # Meaning buying 2 bananas will add a 20% discount

Purchases:
- [123,123] # Bought 2 bananas

Output:
- [('banana', 2, 0.8)]
```

**Potential issues in the code below**

- I'm holding all the information in memory.
- I might be using too many classes to represent the difference pieces of information?

**Code**

Code is best understood when read starting from the `start_process` function

```
class Product:
  def __init__(self, barcode: int, name: str, price: float):
    self.bardcode = barcode
    self.name = name
    self.price = price

  @classmethod
  def parse_product(cls, product_line: str):
    name, barcode_str, price_str = product_line.split(':')
    price = float(price_str)
    barcode = int(barcode_str)
    return cls(barcode, name, price)

class Products:
  def __init__(self):
    self.products = {} # Type: Dict<int, Product>

  def add_product(self, product: Product):
    self.products[product.bardcode] = product

  def get_product(self, product_barcode):
    return self.products[product_barcode]

  @classmethod
  def parse_products(products_cls, products_path: str):
    products = products_cls()
    with open(products_path) as products_lines:
      for product_line in products_lines:
        product = Product.parse_product(product_line)
        products.add_product(product)
    return products

class ProductPurchase:
  def __init__(self, barcode: int, quantity = 1, discount = 0.0):
    self.barcode = barcode
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.discount = discount

class DiscountRule:
  def __init__(self, product_barcode: int, min_quantity: int, discount_amount: float):
    self.product_barcode = product_barcode
    self.min_quantity = min_quantity
    self.discount_amount = discount_amount

  @classmethod
  def parse(cls, discount_rule: str):
    barcode_str, min_quantity_str, discount_amount_str = discount_rule.split(':')
    return cls(int(barcode_str), int(min_quantity_str), float(discount_amount_str))

class DiscountRules:
  def __init__(self):
    self.dicounts = {} # Type: Dict<int, DiscountRule>

  def add_discount(self, discount: DiscountRule):
    self.dicounts[discount.product_barcode] = discount

  def apply_discount(self, purchase: ProductPurchase):
    if purchase.barcode not in self.dicounts:
      return
    discount = self.dicounts[purchase.barcode]
    if purchase.quantity < discount.min_quantity:
      return
    purchase.discount = discount.discount_amount

  @classmethod
  def parse_discount_rules(cls, rules_path: str):
    rules = cls()
    with open(rules_path) as rules_lines:
      for rule_line in rules_lines:
        rule = DiscountRule.parse(rule_line)
        rules.add_discount(rule)
    return rules


class Purchases:
  def __init__(self):
    self.purchases = {} # Type: Dict<int, ProductPurchase>

  def add_purchase(self, purchased_barcode: int):
    if purchased_barcode in self.purchases:
      self.purchases[purchased_barcode].quantity += 1
    else:
      self.purchases[purchased_barcode] = ProductPurchase(purchased_barcode)

  def get_purchases(self):
    for purchase in self.purchases.values():
      yield purchase


class Checkout:
  def __init__(self, purchases: Purchases, products: Products, discount_rules: DiscountRules):
    self.purchases = purchases
    self.products = products
    self.discount_rules = discount_rules

  def check_out(self):
    result = []
    for purchase in self.purchases.get_purchases():
      self.discount_rules.apply_discount(purchase)
      product = self.products.get_product(purchase.barcode)
      price = _calculate_price(product.price, purchase.quantity, purchase.discount)
      result.append((product.name, purchase.quantity, price))

    return result

def _calculate_price(price, quantity, discount):
  return str(round(price * quantity * (1.0 - discount), 2))

def start_process(products_paths: str, discounts_path: str, scanner_input):
  purchases = Purchases()
  for purchased_barcode in scanner_input:
    purchases.add_purchase(purchased_barcode)

  products = Products.parse_products(products_paths)
  discount_rules = DiscountRules.parse_discount_rules(discounts_path)
  checkout = Checkout(purchases, products, discount_rules)

  return checkout.check_out()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) so you don't have to write boilerplate for your data containers.
- You don't really need `Products`, `DiscountRules`, and `Purchases` when you could just have `dict[int, Product]`, `dict[int, DiscountRule]`, and `dict[int, ProductPurchase]` respectively. The existence of these classes makes the code harder to read.
- `Checkout` doesn't need to be a class. You can just declare the method `check_out`. [If you find yourself writing a class that only has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you probably don't need a class](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html).
- [Don't store currency as floats](https://blog.agentrisk.com/you-better-work-in-cents-not-dollars-2edb52cdf308). Use a currency's smallest unit so you can store it as an integer. The main idea is to avoid rounding errors that come up in floating point arithmetic. For example, if `Product`'s `price` is the price in US currency, it should be an integer representing the price in cents, not dollars.
- You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the scanned barcodes, which gives you something like a `dict[int, int]` (barcode -> quantity). Then you can use this to create a collection of `ProductPurchase`s later.
- I see type hints being used, but not consistently. Type hints should be added for method return types as well.
- This is personal preference, but for the methods that parse a string into a data container type like `Product`, instead of the names `parse_product`, `parse`, etc. I would name it `from_string` so the usage is more self-documenting, e.g. `Product.from_string(s)`.

### Refactored version

```python
from __future__ import annotations

from collections import Counter
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Product:
    barcode: int
    name: str
    price: int  # in the currency's smallest unit, e.g. cents for US currency

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(product: str) -> Product:
        barcode, name, price = product.split(":")
        return Product(int(barcode), name, int(price))


@dataclass
class DiscountRule:
    barcode: int
    min_quantity: int
    discount_amount: int  # percentage, e.g. 20 => 20% discount

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(discount_rule: str) -> DiscountRule:
        barcode, min_quantity, discount_amount = discount_rule.split(":")
        return DiscountRule(
            int(barcode), int(min_quantity), int(discount_amount)
        )


@dataclass
class ProductPurchase:
    product: Product
    quantity: int
    discount: int  # percentage, e.g. 20 => 20% discount

    @property
    def cost(self) -> float:
        return self.product.price * self.quantity * (100 - self.discount) / 100

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        discount_text = (
            f" (with {self.discount}% discount)" if self.discount > 0 else ""
        )
        return f"{self.quantity}x {self.product.name}{discount_text}  {self.cost / 100:.2f}"


def calculate_product_purchase(
    products: dict[int, Product],
    discounts: dict[int, DiscountRule],
    barcode: int,
    quantity: int,
) -> ProductPurchase:
    product = products[barcode]
    discount_pct = (
        discount.discount_amount
        if (discount := discounts.get(barcode, None))
        and quantity >= discount.min_quantity
        else 0
    )
    return ProductPurchase(product, quantity, discount_pct)


def print_receipt(
    products_path: str, discounts_path: str, purchases: list[int]
) -> None:
    with open(products_path) as p_file, open(discounts_path) as d_file:
        products = {
            p.barcode: p for line in p_file if (p := Product.from_string(line))
        }
        discounts = {
            d.barcode: d
            for line in d_file
            if (d := DiscountRule.from_string(line))
        }

    for barcode, quantity in Counter(purchases).items():
        product_purchase = calculate_product_purchase(
            products, discounts, barcode, quantity
        )
        print(product_purchase)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_receipt(
        "products.txt", "discounts.txt", [123, 123, 123, 123, 789, 789]
    )
```

#### products.txt

```
123:banana:50
789:apple:40
```

#### discounts.txt

```
123:2:20
```

Comment: great comments! why not having calculate product_purchase as a class method? also, why do you store references to classes using barcodes and not the class itself? also, I see multiple discounts stored by value and in +1 place, can't this be a problem if such discount needs to be changed during run time?

Comment: @miquelvir `calculate_product_purchase` _could_ be a class method, yes, but I personally didn't like the call pattern of `ProductPurchase.calculate_product_purchase(...)`. Personal preference, really.

Comment: @miquelvir Re `also, why do you store references to classes using barcodes and not the class itself?`: I'm not sure I quite follow you here. Are you asking why I didn't model `Product` to contain a list of `DiscountRule`s? If so, I didn't feel like that was really necessary and would introduce unwanted coupling. When I think of a `Product` in this problem, it clearly needs an id (barcode), a name, and a unit price. But I don't think it should hold a `DiscountRule` or a `list[DiscountRule]`, i.e. I think its model should exist independently of `DiscountRule`.

Comment: (continuing from the previous comment) For example, what if in the future there is a new kind of `DiscountRule` that offers a discount if you purchase everything in a list of distinct `Product`s (e.g. buy one apple and one banana for 10% off)? Then that coupling might need to be refactored out in that case.

Comment: Re the part about discounts stored by value and discounts changing at runtime: If the discounts change, then all one needs to do is recalculate all the product purchases using the updated discounts. In other words, simply re-running the program with the changed discounts file, since the flow we have here is `load data & input -> perform calculations -> print report -> exit program`. The data flow is unidirectional, and I don't think there's anything in the problem statement that would suggest that we need to worry about discounts being modified while the program is running.

Comment: your logic makes sense  @Setris, I was however asking about why you store barcode in DiscountRule, and not a Product. If discount rule refers to a product, is not it more useful to store the product itself, and not a barcode we can use to get it from somewhere?

Comment: @miquelvir Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, so for `DiscountRule`, I could definitely see storing `Product` there if we wanted to for example print each `DiscountRule` in a human-friendly format, e.g. `Buy at least 2x Apple, save 20%`. In this case there wasn't really a need to do that, so I kept the model that's closer to what @Omar had in the original code. Note that for `ProductPurchase` I am keeping a reference to `Product` instead of just the `barcode` because it's needed for the pretty-print `__str__`.

Comment: makes sense, I still think its cleaner to hold the product however

Answer (score 3):

- Indentation is not a multiple of 4, while PEP8 establishes that it should.
- No entry-point to your script (if __ name __ == '__ main __'...).
- Parse_product was getting the name before the barcode, while the question establishes the order is the opposite one.
- Class products is basically a dictionary. It does not make sense to me to have a whole class to just cover a dictionary (not actually exposing all of the useful interface form it) just for the parse_products class method. I see 4 options: inherit from dict, this way at least its a proper dict, have ProductUtils and just have the utility function parse_products, or have a function parse_products, have the parse_products utility inside the Product class, no need to have Product and Products (if products its basically a dict). All of them seem better to me.
- Calculate price makes no sense to have it as a utility function. If it computes the discounted price of a purchase, why not have it in the Purchase class?
- Do you have some background working with DBs? The ProductPurchase structure makes sense in the context of a database. But in this OOP design, why not just having ProductCart? Also, instead of storing barcodes, store the actual products (we don't loose much space for a single object reference we already have, and it will be much more useful than just having the key to it)!
- Similarly, purchases is just a dict, so why not inherit from it to get its full utility and just override what we need to be different. Also, add_purchase is misleading, since you add a product/barcode, not a purchase (since the purchase is generated within the method).
- The DiscountRules class seems to me un-necessary. Why not store the discounts in the Product class itself?
- In general, no docstrings in any of the methods nor comments anywhere.
- The check_out method basically only needs to go through the purchases. Essentially, it does nothing and thus it is not needed.
- Other comments in the code

This is the final version I suggest:

```
from typing import Iterable, Dict


class Product:
    def __init__(self, barcode: int, name: str, price: float):
        self.barcode = barcode
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.discounts = []

    @classmethod
    def parse_product(cls, product_line: str):
        barcode, name, price = product_line.split(':')
        return cls(int(barcode), name, float(price))

    def add_discount(self, discount: 'DiscountRule'):
        self.discounts.append(discount)


class Products(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Products, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_product(self, product: Product):
        self[product.barcode] = product

    @classmethod
    def parse_products(cls, products_path: str, discount_rules: 'Dict[int, DiscountRule]'):
        products = cls()
        with open(products_path) as products_lines:
            for product_line in products_lines:
                product = Product.parse_product(product_line)

                if product.barcode in discount_rules:
                    product.add_discount(discount_rules[product.barcode])

                products.add_product(product)
        return products


class ProductPurchase:
    def __init__(self, product: Product, quantity: int = 1):
        self.product = product
        self.quantity = quantity

    @property
    def discount(self):
        total_discount = None
        for discount in self.product.discounts:
            if self.quantity >= discount.min_quantity:
                if total_discount is None:
                    total_discount = 0
                total_discount += discount.discount_amount
        return total_discount

    def purchase(self, quantity: int = 1):
        self.quantity += quantity

    @property
    def discounted_price(self):
        return round(self.product.price * self.quantity * (1.0 - self.discount), 2)


class DiscountRule:
    def __init__(self, product_barcode: int, min_quantity: int, discount_amount: float):
        self.product_barcode = product_barcode
        self.min_quantity = min_quantity
        self.discount_amount = discount_amount

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, discount_rule: str):
        barcode_str, min_quantity_str, discount_amount_str = discount_rule.split(':')
        return cls(int(barcode_str), int(min_quantity_str), float(discount_amount_str))

    @classmethod
    def parse_discount_rules(cls, rules_path: str) -> 'Iterable[int, DiscountRule]':
        with open(rules_path) as rules_lines:
            for rule_line in rules_lines:
                discount_rule = DiscountRule.parse(rule_line)
                yield discount_rule.product_barcode, discount_rule


class Purchases(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def purchase(self, product: Product):
        if product.barcode in self:
            self[product.barcode].purchase()
        else:
            self[product.barcode] = ProductPurchase(product)


class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, purchases: Purchases, products: Products):
        self.purchases = purchases
        self.products = products

    @classmethod
    def init_from_files(cls, products_path: str, discounts_path: str, scanner_input: list):
        discount_rules = DiscountRule.parse_discount_rules(discounts_path)

        products = Products.parse_products(products_path, dict(discount_rules))

        purchases = Purchases()
        for purchased_barcode in scanner_input:
            purchases.purchase(products[purchased_barcode])

        return cls(purchases, products)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cart = ShoppingCart.init_from_files("products.txt", "discounts.txt", [123, 123])

    print("TICKET")
    for purchase in cart.purchases.values():
        print("%s x %s | %s€" % (purchase.quantity, purchase.product.name, purchase.discounted_price))
    print("------")
```

And code with comments on it:

```
from typing import Iterable, List


class Product:
    def __init__(self, barcode: int, name: str, price: float):
        self.barcode = barcode  # bardcode seems a typo for barcode
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.discounts = []

    @classmethod
    def parse_product(cls, product_line: str):
        barcode, name, price = product_line.split(':')
        """price = float(price_str)
        barcode = int(barcode_str) >>> un-needed in two steps """
        return cls(int(barcode), name, float(price))

    def add_discount(self, discount: 'DiscountRule'):
        self.discounts.append(discount)


class Products(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Products, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_product(self, product: Product):
        self[product.barcode] = product

    """def get_product(self, product_barcode):
        return self[product_barcode]
        
        >>> no need for this method, the dict already implements a get
        """

    @classmethod
    def parse_products(cls, products_path: str):
        """stick to the cls naming convention
        since it is a class method from the Products class, it is trivial that it is a product_cls
        """
        products = cls()
        with open(products_path) as products_lines:
            for product_line in products_lines:
                product = Product.parse_product(product_line)
                products.add_product(product)
        return products


class ProductPurchase:
    def __init__(self, product: Product, quantity: int = 1):  # >>> type hinting missing
        self.product = product
        self.quantity = quantity
        # self.discount = discount
        """
        >>> instead of storing a hard copy of the discount, which might get corrupted
            if the discount or quantity change, use a property and compute it live
        """

    @property
    def discount(self):
        """ computes the discount, accepts multiple discounts per product now """
        total_discount = None
        for discount in self.product.discounts:
            if self.quantity >= discount.min_quantity:
                if total_discount is None:
                    total_discount = 0
                total_discount += discount.discount_amount
        return total_discount

    def purchase(self, quantity: int = 1):
        """ provide a nice interface for modifying the quantity """
        self.quantity += quantity

    @property
    def discounted_price(self):
        return round(self.product.price * self.quantity * (1.0 - self.discount), 2)


class DiscountRule:
    def __init__(self, product_barcode: int, min_quantity: int, discount_amount: float):
        self.product_barcode = product_barcode
        self.min_quantity = min_quantity
        self.discount_amount = discount_amount

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, discount_rule: str):
        barcode_str, min_quantity_str, discount_amount_str = discount_rule.split(':')
        return cls(int(barcode_str), int(min_quantity_str), float(discount_amount_str))

    @classmethod
    def parse_discount_rules(cls, rules_path: str) -> 'Iterable[DiscountRule]':
        with open(rules_path) as rules_lines:
            for rule_line in rules_lines:
                yield DiscountRule.parse(rule_line)

    @classmethod
    def add_discounts_to_products(cls, discounts: 'Iterable[DiscountRule]', products: Products):
        for discount in discounts:
            if discount.product_barcode in products:
                products[discount.product_barcode].add_discount(discount)


class Purchases(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def purchase(self, product: Product):  # work with objects! not with keys which refer to objects
        if product.barcode in self:
            self[product.barcode].purchase()
        else:
            self[product.barcode] = ProductPurchase(product)

    """def get_purchases(self):
        for purchase in self.values():
            yield purchase
            >>> not needed since now the interface is the actual dict
            """


class ShoppingCart:  # a more meaningful name to the object, check_out is an action/method
    def __init__(self, purchases: Purchases, products: Products):
        self.purchases = purchases
        self.products = products
        # self.discount_rules = discount_rules  >>> not needed anymore

    def check_out(self) -> Iterable:
        """ return an iterable instead of a list, the caller can then do whatever xhe wants """
        for purchase in self.purchases.values():
            yield purchase.product.name, purchase.quantity, purchase.discounted_price

    @classmethod
    def init_from_files(cls, products_path: str, discounts_path: str, scanner_input: list):
        # get products from products_path
        products = Products.parse_products(products_path)

        # get discount_rules from discount_path
        discount_rules = DiscountRule.parse_discount_rules(discounts_path)
        DiscountRule.add_discounts_to_products(discount_rules, products)

        purchases = Purchases()
        for purchased_barcode in scanner_input:
            purchases.purchase(products[purchased_barcode])

        return cls(purchases, products)




"""def get_checkout(products_paths: str, discounts_path: str, scanner_input):
    
    >>> if all the code is using objects, why have a random function and not use those objects?
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cart = ShoppingCart.init_from_files("products.txt", "discounts.txt", [123, 123])
    print(list(cart.check_out()))
```

Comment: Elaborate review, suggesting valid design issues One prime strategy/directive in both software-development and writing (text, not code) is _divide and conquer_ or [modularisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule). This would ease reading/understanding/maintaining of both your answer and the code under review. What about __headings__ and separate __code-blocks__ (modules) to improve structure

Answer (score 2):

Since you are handling **CSV** data, and if you have a well-structured file, there is no need to reinvent the wheel and do the parsing yourself. Python already has a library for this purpose: [csv — CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Of course it is not impossible that a personal and minimalist implementation could perform better than an established and time-proven module, but this is doubtful. But you can test for yourself.

Another more obvious alternative would be using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Import the data to a dataframe, that can be further manipulated with the result of your calculations.

And you have yet one more option: a **database**. You could use the **sqlite** module and import the files to tables. I think this option is well suited for your purpose. You can get the job done with a few joins and possibly some subselects depending on the need. But here this is just a very basic join of 3 tables that you need.

SQLite can import CSV files in bulk but you'll need to invoke the shell for this. See for example: https://wizardforcel.gitbooks.io/sqlite-doc-en/content/30.html

NB: the database file does not even have to be stored on disk, you can create an in-memory DB that is disposed after your program has executed. But if you have large datasets and you are worried about memory consumption, then use a DB file. If you are on Linux you can use a temporary file on /tmp, which is normally tmpfs (= fast data access).

Either way, it is going to be easier to perform your calculations (rebates) in bulk, when all the data has been imported. You can create views, temporary tables etc. If your needs become more complex, then you can use a mix of Python and SQlite, or choose a database that supports stored procedures to handle more sophisticated computations.

I don't think the approach you've chosen is optimal. At the very least I would recommend that you separate these two concerns in your coding: the import of data, and the transformation of data. My suggestion is to reconsider the tools available for the job. It seems to me that you can ditch those classes and simplify the job a lot if you choose the DB approach.